# JavaScript. Создание файла

Tags: javascript, c#, vue.js, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Пишу на Vue.js. Работаю над редактором фото для аватара.
Использую vue-cropperjs для обрезки изображений.

Задача:
Нужно обрезать изображение, после чего загрузить его на сервер. Сервер на C# ASP.NET Core.
Обрезанное изображение получить удается. Записывается оно в таком виде:

*data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ*

Теперь вопрос, как мне записать его в файл, после чего загрузить на сервер?
Больше интересует преобразование в файл.

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: `как мне записать его в файл, после чего загрузить на сервер` именно в этом порядке? Не обратном? Куда вы файл писать на клиенте хотите? Что мешает на сервер отправить прямо эту строку + имя файла и на сервере уже сохранять?

Comment: Честно говоря, я не вижу разницы. То ли клиент будет записывать в файл или сервер. А если разница есть, то готов прислушаться.

Comment: Ничего не мешает. Абсолютно. Только я не пойму, как это сделать. Я так понимаю, здесь замешан System.IO.

Comment: Если вам без разницы, клиент будет писать файл на компьютер юзера или сервер на серверный хард - то я теряюсь в вашей постановке задачи.

Comment: OK. Попробую расставить заново. Допустим, как я могу реализовать следующую задачу: Отправить строку и имя файла на сервер, а сервер сам сохранит файл. ?

Comment: @General2001 вам тут намекают что браузер не умеет работать с диском

Comment: В таком случае, как можно реализовать такое с сервером?

Comment: @General2001 клиент сразу отправляет серверу данные, как вам уже и сказали

Comment: например строкой

Comment: Я понял. Но как преобразовать ее в файл?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91289/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-general2001).